# Why is my variable empty, not undefined in JS?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, filereader

I am trying to make a programming language. I have a global variable called textToRead, which is the text in the file. However, it's resulting in an empty variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="text">This is where your code will appear</p>
  <p id="test">This is where your code will appear</p>
  <p id="output">This is where you will see the output</p>
  <tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button>
      <td>
  </tr>
  <button onclick="run()">Interpret .txt as code</button>
  <script>
    let textToRead;
    function loadFileAsText() {
      var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = textFromFileLoaded;
      };
      fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = fileReader.result;
      textToRead = fileReader.result;
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = textToRead;
    }

    function run() {
      if (textToRead.includes("output")) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = textToRead;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = textToRead + "error";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not getting any errors, and my variable textToRead isn't undefined, because it's resulting in a value of nothing, not undefined. The part where you can view the page is working, but the variable used for parsing the string isn't.

Comment: I loaded an image file and i saw an output (albeit scrambled as expected)

Comment: The output is working, but the variable isn't.

Comment: Duplicate? [FileReader.result return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658388/filereader-result-return-null)